# Need help in understand how partial derivatives are taken in ML course from Coursera

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I did not study multivariable calc, but I need to understand how the following derivatives are taken. I will really really appreciate your help!
I took it from Coursera ML course.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we take partial derivative of $\theta_0$, treat $\theta_1$ as a constant.

Hence 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} J(\theta_0, \theta_1) &=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m (\theta_0+\theta_1x^{(i)}-y^{(i)})^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} \left(\theta_0+\theta_1x^{(i)}-y^{(i)}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m 2\left(\theta_0+\theta_1x^{(i)}-y^{(i)}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0}\left(\theta_0+\theta_1x^{(i)}-y^{(i)}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left(\theta_0+\theta_1x^{(i)}-y^{(i)}\right).1
\\&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left(h_{\theta}(x^{(i)})-y^{(i)}\right)
\end{align*}

From the first line to second line, I just move the derivative inside (just like a regular derivative)

From second to third line, I applied chain rule.

From third line to to fourth line, I differentiate with respect to $\theta_0$, treating $\theta_1$ as a constant.

Similarly when we differeniate with respect to $\theta_1$, notice that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1}\left(\theta_0+\theta_1x^{(i)}-y^{(i)}\right)=x^{(i)}.$$,

hence we have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} J(\theta_0, \theta_1)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left(h_{\theta}(x^{(i)})-y^{(i)}\right)x^{(i)}$$